# jQuery show element using Data attribute Selector

Tags: jquery

Cannot seem to show the the div using the data attribute as a selector.

The container is displayed, but none of the lines are.

```
<div class="container">
    <div data-line="2">Two</div>
</div>
```

using the selector below, it doesn't work

```
$('.container div[data-line="2"]').show();
```

So you guys understand the context...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        $('.container div[data-line="'+ i + '"]').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code. Is the div hidden by default so that `show()` will actually do something? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6QU2U/

Comment: If you can create a jsfiddle that shows the problem, it would help.

Comment: @scrowler yes it is... Here is the fiddle I have been working with that is causing me issues : http://jsfiddle.net/xS39F/

Comment: Did you set the `data` attribute dynamically?

Comment: @user3558931 no. Hardcoded into the HTML

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xS39F/1/ container div is hidden

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you're setting your container div to display none -

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: grey;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
    display: none; // here is the issue
}
```

A simple fix is to change your CSS selector to `div > div {...` Essentially you are showing the children, but since the parent is hidden the children will continue to be hidden too.

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/xS39F/2/

Comment: oh man I'm an idiot. Sometimes I am just careless with CSS because all I really care about is the programming

Answer (score 2):

It's simple just change your css from div {} to .container div {} and its done.